# Socket Communication using Java and C++ at linux

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have implemented an application where I need to use Server socket in Java and Client Socket in C++.They are communicating each other over 127.0.0.1 IP and 4444 port. In our test server(Linux) application are working fine but in production server, socket is neither accepting anything nor client is sending any data.Though the OS are exactly same to each other.

Any idea how I can overcome the same?

Should I've to check security,firewall or anything else ?

**Client Socket  C++ (Demo)
=========================**

```
class tcp_client
{
private:
    int sock;
    std::string address;
    int port;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

public:
    tcp_client();
    bool conn();
    bool send_data(string data);
   // string receive(int);
};

tcp_client::tcp_client()
{
    sock = -1;
    port = 4444;
    address = "127.0.0.1";
}

/**
    Connect to a host on a certain port number
*/
bool tcp_client::conn()
{
    //create socket if it is not already created
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        //Create socket
        sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
        if (sock == -1)
        {
            perror("Could not create socket");
        }
     }
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( address.c_str() );
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );
    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed.## Error");
        return 1;
    }     
    cout<<"Connected\n";
    return true;
}

/**
    Send data to the connected host
*/
bool tcp_client::send_data(string data)
{
    //Send some data
    if( send(sock , data.c_str() , strlen( data.c_str() ) , 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Send failed : ");
        return false;
    }
    cout<<"Data send\n  "<<sock;

    return true;
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    tcp_client c;

        c.conn();  
        c.send_data("Test Class C++ Client \n");   

    return 0;
}
```

**Server Socket - Java (DEMO)
===========================**

```
public class ServerSocketTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            try {  
                StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);

                while(true){

                    System.out.println("Waiting to receive ---->> ");
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("After receive ---->> ");
                    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());                     
                    String tmp; 
                    while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                        inputLine.append(tmp);
                        System.out.println(tmp);
                    }
                    //use inputLine.toString(); here it would have whole source
                    dis.close();            
                    clientSocket.close();  
              }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
              // e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clearify.. On production server, both applications are running on same device? Have you checked whether the server is actually listening on the port? - You could use `netstat -tulpn` to check that. And did you try to connect to server using tools like netcat? - E.g. `netcat 127.0.0.1 4444`

Comment: 1. Yes, both are in same device.

Comment: 2. Yes,Server is listening the port as well

Comment: Did you debug the c++ code to check if conn() fails or not. Btw conn returns true, even if it fails in your code.

Comment: You are right in code return statement is is my mistake. Thanks for that. But this same code is run in our test server. Is there anything I have to configure in my Production server.

Comment: Did you try to connect to server with a socket test tool and send some data? You need to test your components individally to locate the problem.

Comment: No, I'm not doing this.I'll check let you know.

Thanks for the help you both.